# What is the explanation of the abbreviation Gii in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, gii

What is the explanation of the abbreviation **Gii** in Yii?

I know that Gii is the web-based code generation tool of Yii Framework.

Yii means "Yes it is!", What does **Gii** mean?

Comment: I do not understand you question.. what expansion of GII ? can you post a link to where you have read this, or what do you mean by this?

Comment: Yii : Yes It Is.. Similarly.. Gii:______?

Comment: so you mean the EXPLANATION of Gii ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the tool to create automated script based on Yii.
[Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18627-what-is-it-gii/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does not mean anything special. It is the **G** enerator for Y **ii** so this just may stand for this. Or you can say "Generator It Is" or sth similar.

see also a short discussion [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37902-gii/)